# 1-parameter group of a vector field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, flows

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection of $g$ and let $X,Y$ be vector fields on $M$. If $\lbrace \phi _t \rbrace $ is the 1-parameter group of $X$ then what is the relation between $\nabla _YX$ and $\phi _{t*}Y$($\phi _{t*}$ is the differential of $\phi _t$)?

Answer (score 3):

The Levi-Civita  connection has torsion zero so that

$$ \nabla_XY- \nabla_Y X= [X,Y] . $$

On the other hand, $[X,Y]$ is the Lie derivative of $Y$ along $X$.  Arnold  called this the ``*fisherman's derivative*'' due to its description  in terms of the action of the flow $\Phi^t$. (Note that I use the time $t$ as  a superscript for typographical reasons, and not only.)  More precisely

$$ [X, Y]_{p_0}=- \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}\Bigl(\,\Phi^t_* Y(p_{-t})- Y(p_0)\,\Bigr),\;\;p_0\in M,\;\;p_t= \Phi^t(p_0),\;\;\forall t\in\mathbb{R}. $$

For a proof  of the last equality [see  section 3.1.1 of these notes.](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Denote $\phi_t = e^{t X}$. By definition of [Lie derivative of a vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#The_Lie_derivative_of_a_vector_field)

$$ \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}e^{-t X}_* Y = [X,Y] = \nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X.$$

The second equality holds since the Levi-Civita connection has zero torsion.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C(X)$ be the horizontal lift (a vector field on $TM$) of the vector field $X$ with respect to the the Levi Civita connection. Then the flow $Fl^{C(X)}_t$ is parallel transport along each flow line of $Fl^X_t$, and we have 
$$
\nabla_ XY = \frac{d}{dt}|_0 (Fl^{C(X)}_{-t}\circ Y \circ Fl^X_t). 
$$
For a proof see 24.2 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf)